# How to select all of a unique attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to find all the Records that have unique email addresses. I am trying to perform this :

```
@uniq_referrals = []
CardReferral.all.select{|a| @uniq_referrals << a.email}
@referral_count = @uniq_referrals.uniq.each{|a|CardReferral.find_by_email(a)}
```

But I would like to do it in a single call. Is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you use activerecord ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
CardReferral.select("distinct(email), other_field_you_need")
```

where `other_field_you_need` it's a list of  field name you need to use from the objects you get from ActiveRecord.

To get the count of unique email record you can use:

```
CardReferral.count("distinct(email)")
```

Comment: More simply, how would I just get a `count` of these uniq objects?

Comment: Wow this is incredible! Thanks so much.

Comment: is there a way to get all attributes without having to list them?   this could be an error source when you add attributes... .

Answer (score 0):

I would like to find all the Records that have unique email addresses. I am trying to perform this :

```
@uniq_referrals = []
CardReferral.all.select{|a| @uniq_referrals << a.email}
@referral_count = @uniq_referrals.uniq.each{|a|CardReferral.find_by_email(a)}
```

But I would like to do it in a single call. Is that possible?

I think that it would help you:

```
Model.group("email")
```

when we group all the record by email id then you will find all the record that have uniq email. if some record have same id then you will get first record.

[image]

please prefer to image for more understanding.
If you could not get yet, then i will explain elaborate more.

Comment: I did not get what your meaning

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.